# Establishing a downchannel stream to alexa (AVS) using https in node js is giving parse error

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to establish alexa voice downchannel stream in nodejs using https but i am getting parse error. here is the code

```
var https = require('https'); 

var fs = require('fs'); 

//read the accesstoken from text file.
var accessToken = fs.readFileSync('accessToken.txt','utf8');

 var options = {
    host: 'avs-alexa-na.amazon.com',
    path: '/v20160207/directives',
    scheme : 'https',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ${accessToken}'}
  };


var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});
req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
req.end();
```

when i am running the above code, i am getting error

```
problem with request: Parse Error
```

could you please help me where i am doing mistake.